# Subfigures in beamer documents

Tags: beamer, numbering, subfloats

I'm using beamer package to produce slides. I put many figures on a slide by using the subfigure package. The problem is that for captions, the subfigure are labeled "a", "b".. "m", "n" and so on, for subfigures appearing on different slides. How could I reset the subfigure numbering when passing to a new slide?

Comment: Using figure and subfigure in beamer seems like a conflict of interest.  Figure is for floating material, which you don't want for beamer. Why not just use the columns environment?

Comment: I did not know about this environment. Thank you.

Comment: I have 4 graphs and I want to put them on one beamer slide with a note at the top of each. How do I do this in beamer?

Comment: Adding the reset counter in every frame can be tedious when you have too many and you must add them at different times. The answer that gave Stefan didn't work with me, but I found [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27838/beamer-subfigure-numbering) solution in another question, so I post it here: what you should add is, instead of figure, framenumber: `\makeatletter \@addtoreset{subfigure}{framenumber} \makeatother` always in the preamble. I've just tried it and it works. Regards!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of doing this for every figure, you could define it once in the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{subfigure}{figure}
\makeatother
```

Alternatively, using the `chngcntr` package:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{subfigure}{figure}
```

Though I would expect such a reset per figure as default subfigure behavior, but you did not post your code.

Comment: I guess this is a conflict between beamer and subfigure; beamer has its own definitions of `figure` environments (which are non-floating in beamer).

Comment: Neither of these solutions works for me under MikTeX 2.9. The first one just doesn't work, and the second one gives me an error to the effect that `subfigure` is not a counter.

Comment: @SSilk: perhaps you didn't load the subfigure package.

Comment: These two don't work for me either. TeX Live 2015

Comment: never mind, these work, but of course one has to have a **caption to get the counter reset** which I forgot

Answer (score 24):

### Update

Since version `2015/09/17 v3.3-111` of the `caption` package, beamer and subcaption **are** again compatible.

You shouldn't be using the obsolete `subfigure` package in modern LaTeX documents; you could use the [`subfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig) package instead (the `subcaption` package is not compatible with `beamer` for old versions):

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subfloat[First subfigure\label{fig:a}]{\includegraphics[height=2cm,width=3cm]{example-image}}\qquad
  \subfloat[Second subfigure\label{fig:b}]{\includegraphics[height=2cm,width=3cm]{example-image-a}}
\caption{A figure}
\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
  
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subfloat[Third subfigure\label{fig:c}]{\includegraphics[height=2cm,width=3cm]{example-image-b}}\qquad    
  \subfloat[Fourth subfigure\label{fig:d}]{\includegraphics[height=2cm,width=3cm]{example-image-c}}
\caption{Another figure}
\label{fig:2}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

<sub>When I first wrote this answer `subcaption` and `beamer` were not explicitly incompatible; since this has changed, now I updated my answer with `subfig`. Thanks to **kww** who noticed this in [`his/her comment`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4530/subfigures-in-beamer-documents/17146?noredirect=1#comment613436_17146).</sub>

<sub>Things have changed one more time: `subcaption` and `beamer` **are** compatible again.</sub>

Comment: The answer can't be moved to another question. You need to copy it manually and delete this one. Just click on edit and copy&paste the whole text should work including the images.

Comment: Note that the `@usename` notification doesn't work in answers or questions.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: I'll then wait and see if Jim Silverton moves his answer to a new question and then I'll move my answer accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina I receive the "! Package caption Error: The 'subcaption' package does not work correctly" by loading `\usepackage{caption}` and `\usepackage{subcaption}`.

Comment: @kww Yes, This was an old answer and 4 years ago there was no incompatibility between `(sub)caption` and `beamer`. Since that time, the packages became incompatible with `beamer`. However, `subfig` can still be used. Give me some minutes to update the answer. Thanks for pointing me out to this problem.

Comment: There is still a bug in the ```caption``` package (version ```caption 2016/02/21 v3.3-144```) that causes this error: ```! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \@@magyar@captionfix 
                                
l.76 \begin{document}```. I had this problem only with ```babel``` in ```beamer``` documents (works fine with ```scrreprt```), but I've found a fix: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/426090/26292

Comment: \subfig \subfloat breaks down beamer's {columns}

Answer (score 12):

Solved: added `\setcounter{subfigure}{0}` before each `\begin{figure}`.

Comment: Adding `\setcounter{subfigure}{0}` before each `\begin{figure}` worked perfectly for me. It is especially usefull when you want to reset it inside a frame (e.g. when you are making a poster using beamer you only have one frame).