# Beamer + subfigure numbering

Tags: beamer, subfloats

When using beamer with the subfigure package, the subfigure labels (a), (b) etc. are not reset at the beginning of a new figure.

Example:

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage{subfigure}  
    \begin{document}


    \begin{frame}
        \begin{figure}[htbp]
            \centering
            \subfigure[Text 1]{Testing subfigure}

            \subfigure[Text 2]{Testing subfiguare even more}      
        \end{figure}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        \begin{figure}[htbp]
            \centering
            \subfigure[Text 1]{Testing subfigure}

            \subfigure[Text 2]{Testing subfiguare even more}      
        \end{figure}
    \end{frame}

    \end{document}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: The [`subfigure` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfigure) is obsolete. Use the [`subfig` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig) package instead.

Comment: You should use `subcaption` instead of the deprecated `subfigure`. `subfig` is also deprecated.

Comment: `subfig` is not deprecated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

With `beamer`'s heavily redefined environments and macros to its custom overlay specification, the `subfigure` counter does not reset at the start of every `figure` environment. Easiest is to insert

```
\setcounter{subfigure}{0}% Reset subfigure counter
```

between the two frames (or before the next frame). If you're willing to have the frame be the designated "master" counter, you could add

```
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{subfigure}{framenumber}% subfigure counter resets every frame
\makeatother
```

at your document start. Alternatively, if you want to tie the `subfigure` counter to a `figure` (rather than a `frame`), you could use

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{\setcounter{subfigure}{0}}% Resets subfigure counter at start of figure environment
```