# Subfigures in beamer in 2018

Tags: beamer, graphics

I recently downloaded the 2018 MacTex suite, and the following MWE fails to compile,

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Testing MWE
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

with error code

```
./Untitled.tex:3: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \@@magyar@captionfix
```

> > So, what is the "correct" way of adding side-by-side subfigures with captions now?

Comment: i can confirm this error (recent version of `beamer`). seems to be bug. you should wait to be removed :-(.

Comment: I think this might be https://github.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/issues/7. Can you update your packages with `tlmgr` and see if the error persist? See also (duplicate) https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/426088/35864

Comment: @moewe I updated all my packages using the Tex-Live utility, and the problem still persists.

Comment: Mhh, the relevant update of the `caption` package arrived on my TeX live mirror this morning. In an update I made a few seconds ago I got the correct version and you MWE works again. Maybe your mirror is a bit slower and takes until later today or tomorrow. In the meantime you can employ the workaround in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426088/ (the duplicate question).