# compatibility problem \pdfmapfile{+sansmathaccent.map} with usepackage{subfig} and usepackage{subcaption}

Tags: beamer

I'm using beamer to create my master presentation. I need to use `\pdfmapfile{+sansmathaccent.map}` due to in equations (math environments) it is necessary.

The problem is when I use `usepackage{subfig}` or `usepackage{subcaption}` to put subfigures, I get: `Undefined control sequence. \begin{document}`. Somebody knows how to fix it?

Comment: please show the actual error from the log file (which will show which command is undefined)

Comment: Undefined control sequence. \begin{document}
Redefining amsmath commands \dddot and \ddddot.
Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref) removing `\color'
Overfull \vbox (0.87134pt too high) detected

Comment: No that is not the format of a tex error message and does not show which command is undefined, it is probably a "summary" given by your editor, show the exact lines from the log file in a code block in your question (the `{}` button) so lines are preserved)

Comment: You mean this one?:! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \@@magyar@captionfix 
l.46 \begin{document}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Comment: `\@@magyar@captionfix` means imho that you should update the caption package.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/426637/2388

Comment: @LuisEnriqueAyalaHernandez yes although it would have been much easier to understand if you'd put it in the question in a code block, not in comments so that `\@@magyar@captionfix` was, as it says, at the end of the line:-)