# how can I remove the Figure label

Tags: beamer, floats, captions

I am trying to make slides

```
\documentclass[11pt] {beamer}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\section{my photos}
\begin{frame}
\footnotesize\textbf  Is this the same as previous figure? 
\begin{figure}[h!]
\caption{This is amazing photo}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{photo1.jpg}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This works file but it print "Figure" on top of figure before the caption.

Comment: `frame` with `article`? Floats on slides? Captions? You are confusing something.

Comment: @Johannes_B I am making slides

Comment: I understand. `article` does not provide frames. People usually use the `beamer` classer for that stuff. Also, do not use a `figure` environment on slides/frames. And if you don't want a label, do not use a caption.

Comment: @Johannes_B I corrected it above

Comment: @Mico please tell me how, I am not that great at latex , what should I use instead ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it something like this you're trying to obtain?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{my photos}
\footnotesize\textbf Is this the same as previous figure?
\begin{figure}[h!]
\caption{This is an amazing photo}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{TasmanianDevil.jpg}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I liked your answer already

Comment: I get an error saying `./test.tex4: Undefined control sequence. <argument> \@@magyar@captionfix` I updated all my packages but still have the same error

Comment: Could you post a small, but complete, example showing the problem?

Comment: @Learner This is an incompatibility of the `caption` package and the LaTeX 2018 release. It was fixed on April 2018 so updating the `caption` package should help. See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426088/texlive-pretest-2018-beamer-and-subfig-collide

Comment: @Bernard It seems to work now, In my previous presentation, I could put the url in the footnote but Marc said you are not allowed to use it !!! also I want to know how to take the footnote to the left side ? I posted my example above and I accepted your answer

Comment: Unfortunately, beamer has its own way to manage footnotes (which anyway are not recommended for presentations), and I didn't understand the details on looking at the code. maybe you should ask a new question for this particular subject.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to employ the `caption` package, you could modify the beamer template for the caption like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{caption}{%
  \raggedright
  \insertcaption\par
}

\begin{document}

\section{my photos}
\begin{frame}
\footnotesize\textbf{Is this the same as previous figure?} 
\begin{figure}
\caption{This is amazing photo}
%\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Unrelated to the problem:

- you don't need the `graphicx` package with beamer
- beamer does not have a floating mechanism, adding floating specifier such as [h!] does not make sense
- `\centering` a figure is unnecessary, beamer centres figures by default
- it should be `\textbf{....}` instead of `\textbf ....` (unless you intent to make only one letter bold)