# Error only with letter ì

Tags: beamer, accents, overleaf

I get an error with the letter ì but not with the other accented letters àèòù, I post the preamble below (Look the EDIT below, the code that I posted doesn't matter):

```
\documentclass[10pt, aspectratio=1610]{beamer}

\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,enumerate}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amscd}
\usepackage[]{units}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\newcommand\paraitem{%
 \quad
 \makebox[\labelwidth][r]{%
 \makelabel{%
 \usebeamertemplate{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}}}\hskip\labelsep}

\newcommand\NoIndent[1]{%
    \par\vbox{\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{#1}}%
}

% Enable colored hyperlinks
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=orangeEX}

% The following three lines are for crossmarks & checkmarks
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%

% Numbered captions of tables, pictures, etc.
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}
\theoremstyle{definition}

\usetheme{Stanford} 
\input{./style_files_unipd/my_beamer_defs.sty}
\logo{\includegraphics[height=0.53in]{./style_files_unipd/unipd_logo_bg.png}}

% commands to relax beamer and subfig conflicts
% see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426088/texlive-pretest-2018-beamer-and-subfig-collide
\makeatletter
\let\@@magyar@captionfix\relax
\makeatother

\title[Sample title]{Sample title}

\begin{document}

\author[Thomas Jhonson]{
    \begin{tabular}{c} 
    \Large
    Thomas Jhonson\\
    \footnotesize \href{mailto:thomas.jhonson@gmail.com}{thomas.jhonson@gmail.com}
\end{tabular}
\vspace{-4ex}}

\institute{
    \vskip 5pt
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=1.00in]{./style_files_unipd/unipd_logo_con_testo.png}
        \end{subfigure}%
        ~ 
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=1.00in]{./style_files_unipd/logoDM.png}
        \end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}
    \vskip 5pt
    Dipartimento di Matematica “Tullio Levi-Civita”\\
    Università degli Studi di Padova\\
    \vskip 3pt
}

\date{July 23, 2020}
% \date{\today}

\begin{noheadline}
\begin{frame}\maketitle\end{frame}
\end{noheadline}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[circle]

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Overview} % Table of contents slide, comment this block out to remove it
    \tableofcontents % Throughout your presentation, if you choose to use \section{} and \subsection{} commands, these will automatically be printed on this slide as an overview of your presentation
\end{frame}

\section{Example}
\begin{frame}{Example}
hello!  % ok
àèòù    % ok
ì       % ERROR!
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

EDIT:
You can reproduce the error just writing the letter "ì" using this template:
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/armlab-latex-beamer-template/hndzfqkwrbyb

The error message says that I used "item" out of a list environment, that I used \spacefactor in internal vertical mode and that I missed a $, all this for an "ì".

Comment: On my system, the "Stanford" theme doesn't exists and obviously your two custom files neither, but without them the code works fine (except for a missing `\end{document}`. So the error seems to be in the code you didn't share.

Comment: How or where is the color `orangeEX` defined?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't contain an attempt to typeset `àèìòù`. It's therefore not usable as a diagnostic tool. Please edit your posting so that the code actually generates the problem behavior you wish to fix.

Comment: The bug requiring `\let\@@magyar@captionfix\relax` has long been fixed.

Comment: For posting a MWE to TeX.SE, you should remove all unnecessary packages.  Do you still get the error if you don't use Beamer?  Do you still get the error if you have only `\documentclass{article} \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \begin{document} àèìòù \end{document}`?

Comment: I added the full code to reproduce the error, and also the template that I used.
You can reproduce the error also with the standard loaded template that I linked, just writing the letter ì.
The color orangeEX is a color that I defined, but, as I said, you can reproduce the error just loading the template without any changes.

Comment: The purposes of a MWE include (1) maybe you're able to isolate and solve the error yourself, (2) saving everyone who wants to help the boring work of isolating the problem.  If you're not willing to go through that process, then the amount that people are willing to help you is lessened.

Comment: The error is caused by the letter "ì", and you can reproduce the error just typing the letter "ì" using this template: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/armlab-latex-beamer-template/hndzfqkwrbyb

what should I do to simplify the work for people who want to help me?
If I could isolate the cause of the error by myself, I wouldn't have posted here.

Comment: I posted a five line tex file in my comment.  Does that give you the same error?  If not, what are the smallest number of packages that you need to reproduce the error?  If orangeEX is not needed for the error, then take it out.  See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/107497 for more suggestions.

Comment: Ok thank you for your guide, I found that the problem was in the file my_beamer_defs.sty of the tampletate that I'm using.
It was defined `\def \i  {\item}` and, I don't know why, but cause of that the accented letter i ( ì ) triggered errors.

Comment: Now you know why you shouldn't use `\def`.